# aws sts maximum number of concurrent tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I was wondering is there a maximum limit on concurrent temporary security credentials generated via STS for a specific IAM role. i.e., first user gets these temporary credentials for 12 hours, second one does the same, how scalable is this approach for `x` number of users? Is there an overall limit that is not mentioned on AWS docs?

Best

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a limit on concurrent temporary credentials for any usage. You can refresh credentials as often as you want (which generates new credentials). A temporary credential is valid (settable) from 900 seconds to 12 hours. Typical refresh logic will refresh at 50% of time or a set value such as 5 minutes. The correct value depends on the service - S3 put needs a longer time than an EC2 instance listing.

The only limitation that I am aware of is API rate limiting (i.e. API calls per second). For this, the error is `ThrottlingException` / HTTP Status Code 400.

If you do hit `ThrottlingException` then implement [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) and try again.

[Error Retries and Exponential Backoff in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html)